# ggplot bar chart adding up to 100%

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Here is my example

```
    mydf = data.frame('col_1' = c('A','A','A', 'B','B'),
 'col_2' = c('positive', 'negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'positive'))
    mydf
    ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x = col_1, fill = col_2))+ geom_bar(stat='count')
```

Here is what it produces: 
[image: bar plot]

I would like bar to add up to 100%. So first bar will show split 33% and 67% and second bar will be 100 %

I know how to manipulate data, but I don't know how to cast it into format necessary for ggplot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See `position_fill()`

Comment: @Henrik Thank you so much, I searched web for 30 minutes and could not find it.

Comment: No, sometimes you just don't hit the right terms ;). I found a relevant post which has a `ggplot` answer pointing to `fill`, and close your question. I will see if I can edit that post and title to make it somewhat more searchable.

Comment: Edited the linked post. Hopefully it will now be easier to find for future searches.